# Use Plink to execute command (Oracle SQL query) on remote server over SSH

Tags: sql, ssh, oracle11g, putty

Currently I'm doing this: start `putty.exe`, input remote server IS and select SSH login, then input server username and password. Then I have to enter `sqlplus` to enter into database, next I put database user and password and run select query. Get output logs on my PC.

I want to automate the process using Plink or any other tool.

Answer (score 2):

As you already know, you can use `plink` (from PuTTY package) to automate remote command execution.

The `plink` has the command-line switch `-m`, that you use to specify a *local* file with the command to execute on the remote server.

```
plink user@host -pw password -m command.txt
```

See [Using the command-line connection tool Plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html)

---

The next step is to automate the remote command.

I do not know `sqlplus`. But from [A Using SQL Command Line](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sqlplus.htm), I assume the command (to be saved into the *local* file `command.txt`) is like:

```
sqlplus dbuser/dbpassword @query.txt
```

Where the `query.txt` is a *remote* file with the query to execute on the server.

---

Finally to save the query output, redirect the `plink` to a *local* file (`results.txt`):

```
plink user@host -pw password -m command.txt > results.txt
```

---

If you are executing one command only, you can specify it directly on the `plink` command-line, avoiding the separate script file:

```
plink user@host -pw password sqlplus dbuser/dbpassword @query.txt > results.txt
```